# Django ManyToManyField renders as object() instead of description

Tags: python, django, forms, model, manytomanyfield

I am using Django's ManyToManyField so that my user may make select multiples from check boxes.  This all seems to be working and saving correctly except that the display is showing "Choice Object(1)" instead of the description.

models.py:

```
class Choice(models.Model):
    description = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.description)

class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=20)
    choice = models.ManyToManyField(Choices) #disciplines offered by an academy
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
class PersonForm(models.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model=Person
        fields=('name','choice')
```

person_update_form.html

```
{% block content %}
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.name }}
    {{ form.choice }}

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save Person</button>
  </form>
{% endblock %}
```

My Choice Database has 3 entries: 'Red', 'Green', 'Blue'.  (ie description = 'Red')

When I render my form, instead of seeing a box with:

```
'Red'
'Green'
'Blue'
```

I see a box with:

```
Choice Object(1)
Choice Object(2)
Choice Object(3)
```

Anyone know how to get the display to show the descriptions instead of the object?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to run a for loop.

`{% for foo in form.choice.all %}
    {{ foo }}
{% endfor %}`

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually of higher quality, and are more like to attract upvotes.